# Use android default alarm sound list

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I wan to develop an alarm app for android and I want to use default alarm sound list of android and let user choose alarm sound from the list in new dialogue. I can use default alarm sound with following code:

```
Uri alarm = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), alarm);
        mp.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
public void getRingtones( )
 {
   RingtoneManager ringtoneMgr = new RingtoneManager(this);
   ringtoneMgr.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
   Cursor alarmsCursor = ringtoneMgr.getCursor();
   int alarmsCount = alarmsCursor.getCount();
   if (alarmsCount == 0 && !alarmsCursor.moveToFirst())
   {
   } 
   else 
   {
   ringtonesStrings = new String[alarmsCount];
   ringtonesUris = new String[alarmsCount];
   while(!alarmsCursor.isAfterLast() && alarmsCursor.moveToNext()) {
   int currentPosition = alarmsCursor.getPosition();
   rintonesStrings[currentPosition] =  ringtoneMgr.getRingtone(currentPosition).getTitle(getApplicationContext());
  ringtonesUris[currentPosition] =   ringtoneMgr.getRingtoneUri(currentPosition).toString();

  }
//alarmsCursor.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: what is ringtonesStrings and ringtonesUris ? how can I use the selected tone by uri?

Comment: ringtonesStrings  is the string array for title and ringtonesUris is also array which used while ringtones play